# Android - Database/cursor wont fill

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I got a redicioulous error.

My cursor wont fill with database entries.

The code i have right now is:

```
public HashMap<Integer, Team> getTeamsBasic(int leagueId) {
    System.out.println("TEST!!!" + leagueId);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    HashMap<Integer, Team> teams = null;
    System.out.println("TEST3!");
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Teams WHERE leagueId = ?";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { Integer.toString(leagueId)});
    System.out.println("TEST4!");
    teams = new HashMap<Integer, Team>();
    System.out.println("BOOL: " + c.moveToFirst());
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        System.out.println("TEST5!");

        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Team team = new Team();
            System.out.println("TEST!6");
            team.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            team.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            team.setStadium(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stadium")));
            System.out.println("TES2T!");
            teams.put(team.getId(), team);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        System.out.println("TEAMSIZE: " + teams.size());
    }

    return teams;}
```

The problem is, I KNOW FOR SURE my database.db is filled with the correct items.
As i have downloaded my DB from my phone, and checked it with the same query as my script does.
Except my script gets no output while me doing the same thing in DB Browser for SQLite i get a ton of output:

https://gyazo.com/2a14458f50fd5a836c55a383d65d0d65

Its the exact same query i use when doing it in android as doing it manually.
The leagueId = 1.
Also the output of the BOOL: = FALSE :(

Whats going (wr)on(g)?

Comment: Try to debug your code and probably you will have a better idea.

Comment: @Okas That is exactly what i am doing. Cursor C just wont fill. And i have no clue on why its not filling up.

Comment: Are the values in the `leagueId` column numbers or strings?